# נִפְתַּ֛לְתִּי "my prayer was accepted" notarikon

Tags: midrash, shevatim-12-tribes, vayeitzei, hermeneutics

In [Genesis 30:8](http://www.mechon-mamre.org/p/pt/pt0130.htm#8) Bilhah, Rachel's maidservant, conceived and Rachel named the son Naftali נִפְתַּלְתִּי

It says [here](http://chabad.org/8225#showrashi=true&v=8) that for  נִפְתַּ֛לְתִּי "my prayer was accepted"

> There are many aggadic midrashim that interpret this phrase with the
> method of notarikon, (i.e., each group of letters represents a word).

Can people list a few of those aggadic midrashim or/and in general indicate how to go about looking them up in other cases?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

My Chumash gives the reference to the Medrash Rabbah 71 (8).

In [this Medrash Rabbah](http://www.hebrewbooks.org/pdfpager.aspx?req=14385&hilite=0fc60a02-674a-4c06-8bbf-7cbc49d05dca&st=%D7%A8%D7%97%D7%9C&pgnum=174) it's 71 (11). I see there one notarikon.

> ותאמר רחל נפתולי אלהים נפתלתי וגו׳ . *נופתי פתיתי תליתי אחותי עלי*.
>   א״ר יוחנן נינפה היה לי לעשות לפני אחותי. אילו  שלהתי ואמרתי לו תן דעתך
>   שהם מרמין בך לא היה פורש

which I understand to mean from the commentary:

> נופתי  I was adorned and perfumed and my couch was ready for my
>   marriage to Yaakov, and in my goodness I adorned and perfumed my
>   sister Leah instead of me on the prepared couch with my good will and
>   even...
>
> פתיתי I introduced her in my stead to the marriage chamber and I gave
>   her the secret signs agreed with Yaakov and so
>
> תליתי I raised up
>
> אחותי עלי my sister over me to marry Yaakov and in the merit of this
>   mitzvah I merited this son.

The method to look them up is to take the reference to the Medrash and see the text of the Medrash.